# Python does not write all the lines into .dat file

Tags: python

I am trying to write a list into a .dat file. The length of the list is 72000, but when the program is done and I open the prediciton.dat file, there are only 70596 lines. What is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
ratings = [a list of 72000 float numbers]

output = open("prediciton.dat","w") 
for x in ratings:
    output.write(str(x)+'\n')
```

Comment: I did not get any error

Comment: Close the file.

Comment: Or use `with open(...) as output:`, which closes it for you.

Answer (score 2):

As Colonel Thirty Two said in comments, you do not close the file.

With data as long as 72,000 floats, this is likely to cause your error.

In addition to that, the lesson to learn from this question is to always close open files. Python provides a `with` statement, which does it automatically:

```
with open("prediciton.dat","w") as output:
    for x in ratings:
        output.write(str(x)+'\n')
```

If you do so, when leaving the `with` scope, Python will execute the `__exit__` method of the `output` object, which cleanly closes the file.